# c# windows form app settings in VM

Tags: c#, application-settings

I have a VSTO C#  Outlook plugin that is distributed through ClickOnce install. This works well and has some user settings. These settings are not persistent for users who are using the plugin in a VM environment. Is there another way of saving user settings to allow them to persist between VM sessions?

Comment: Does your organization use roaming profiles?

Comment: Thansk for the question. I am asking the people who know. If they do, then should the app settings carry over from session to session?

Comment: Roaming profiles are not in use..